# Run test phase in maven while skipping validate & compile

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-surefire-plugin, mvn-repo

Working with a large multi-module maven project. Want to run phases as follows

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Then run unit tests. But this fails, even though code is already compiled

```
mvn surefire:test
```

Comment: Why would you like to skip the test in the first run but run the tests then afterwards? Why not in one go? `mvn clean verify` (install is not needed).

Comment: Using maven in CI/CD pipeline. Running like this will create separate logs making it easier to find which step of the build process fails. Want to separate unit test results from install phase. Running 'mvn test'  after install compiles code twice

Comment: Which kind of CI/CD pipeline? Doesn't the CI/CD pipeline show the test results? The results of a test are printed out and install is done also separately ...to be honest I don't understand the problem?

Comment: Using Jenkins. At present, log of every phase is shown within a single check in GitHub. Separating these phases into various steps would show right from GitHub which step failed the build. Specifically, was there a compilation error or some Unit Test failed. If there is other way of integrating maven with CI/CD, please suggest the same

Comment: Are you using pipelines/Jenkinsfile? Self implemented ? How do they look like? Usually you get a blue build if everything is Ok. Yellow if tests failed (report for tests can be looked into) and red if really something bad happens (compile error)...

Comment: You can take a look here for example: https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/Maven/job/maven-box/job/maven/job/MNG-6656/ or others on that Jenkins ...

Comment: What I don't understand is `log of every phase is shown within a single check in GitHub`...what does that mean?

Comment: @khmarbaise Basically running in separate steps would generate separate logs, which is the requirement to easily figure out what failed. Compilation or Unit tests without delving deeper in logs